# sproutcore change image or icon and repaint

Tags: sproutcore, sproutcore-views

I want to change the icon/image in the statechart.js, that is display and hide it a number of times. I tried a icon to a label and a extra childview. Question: How to hide/change the icon/childview programmatically?

With the extra childview I was abled to change the value, but this change is not visible on the screen.

```
    SC.LabelView.design icon: 'icon-heart',
    ..
    heart: SC.ImageView.extend({
                classNames: ['icon-heart'],
                  value: 'heart.png'
                }),

MyApp.mainPage.getPath('mainPane.navigationView.heart').value = 'icon-next';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SproutCore uses the observer pattern to know when values have changed. In order for this to work, SproutCore requires that you use the `set()` and `get()` methods so that it will see the change and can update the display accordingly.

Try changing your last line to:

```
MyApp.mainPage.getPath('mainPane.navigationView.heart').set('value', 'icon-next');
```

Also, you should definitely look at using [Bindings](http://docs.sproutcore.com/#doc=SC.Binding&src=false) to easily bind the value to a controller (or even a plain `SC.Object` for something this simple) and have your view watch for changes there. Quick example:

```
myApp.myController = SC.Object.extend({
  iconValue: 'icon-heart'
})

myApp.myView = SC.ImageView.extend({
  valueBinding: SC.Binding.oneWay('myApp.myController.iconValue')
})
```

Now, later on, you can do the following from within your statechart:

```
myApp.myController.set('iconValue', 'icon-next');
```

and the view should automatically update.

Please post a comment if you run into issues and I'll do my best to help.

Comment: I added the first line of code in the statechart.js, but the first icon (the heart) remains visible, so beside the value, do I  have to change the classNames too? The second code block, where should I put it? I tried several possibilities, but got no success.

Comment: OK, I got the Binding running, in my controller I added heartimage: 'icon-heart', in my mainpage.js heartimage: SC.ImageView.extend({
    classNames: ['icon-heart'],
    classNamesBinding: SC.Binding.oneWay('myApp.myController.heartimage')
   }), and in my statechart.js myApp.myController.set('heartimage','icon-next'); But there is no rerender/repaint?

Comment: You should either use the classNames property OR the value property, not both. Similarly, you should not use classNames and classNamesBinding as they will conflict. I am on my phone right now but will try to get you an example when I get my computer.

Comment: I got a workaround, in MyApp.Mycontroller heartimage: 'icon-noheart', in main_page.js heartimage: SC.View.design({
    value: 'icon-noheart',
    valueBinding: 'myApp.myController.heartimage',
    
    classNamesObserver: function(){
     this.displayDidChange();
    }.observes('value'),
    
    render: function(context, firsttime){
     var value = this.get('value')     
     context.push('<img class="',value, '" />');
    }
   }), and in the statechart.js ... myApp.myController.set('heartimage','icon-heart'); But please explain the difference between value and classNames binding.